# IBM DB2: Generate list of dates between two dates

Tags: sql, db2, db2-400, db2-luw

I need a query which will output a list of dates between two given dates.

For example, if my start date is 23/02/2016 and end date is 02/03/2016, I am expecting the following output:

```
Date
----
23/02/2016
24/02/2016
25/02/2016
26/02/2016
27/02/2016
28/02/2016
29/02/2016
01/03/2016
02/03/2016
```

Also, I need the above using SQL only (without the use of 'WITH' statement or tables). Please help.

Comment: Any particular reason why you don't want to use a `WITH` clause or are you just trying to make the question more challenging for everyone?

Comment: You tagged this with both `db2400` and `db2-luw`.  What platform is this running on?

Comment: I am looking for an SQL only solution, because WITH statement will not work inside a select statement. Also I do not have the permission to create tables.

Comment: I am unsure about the platform, i did google a and found this query "SELECT * FROM SYSIBMADM.ENV_INST_INFO;" and got "DB2 v10.5.0.3", does this help?

Comment: I tried to write the query using connect by and level, but its not working, everytime I am getting an error, but there is no proper error message, I guessing its because of my IDE, I am using DBVisualiser for connecting to DB2. Unfortunately I dont have the sample queries I wrote yesterday with me right now.

Comment: Side note:  If you don't have one, I **REALLY** recommend creating a date dimension table; basically, a table containing each date, and about as many columns as you want indices for.  It makes certain analysis queries much easier, and would make this a simple range query check of `SELECT calendarDate FROM Calendar WHERE calendarDate >= :start AND  calendarDate < :end`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am using ,ostly DB2 for iSeries, so I will give you an SQL only solution that works on it. Currently I don't have an access to the server, so the query is not tested but it should work. **EDIT** Query is already tested and working

```
SELECT
    d.min + num.n DAYS
FROM
    -- create inline table with min max date
    (VALUES(DATE('2015-02-28'), DATE('2016-03-01'))) AS d(min, max)
INNER JOIN
    -- create inline table with numbers from 0 to 999
    (
        SELECT
            n1.n + n10.n + n100.n AS n
        FROM
            (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) AS n1(n)
        CROSS JOIN
            (VALUES(0),(10),(20),(30),(40),(50),(60),(70),(80),(90)) AS n10(n)
        CROSS JOIN
            (VALUES(0),(100),(200),(300),(400),(500),(600),(700),(800),(900)) AS n100(n)
    ) AS num
ON
    d.min + num.n DAYS<= d.max
ORDER BY
    num.n;
```

if you don't want to execute the query only once, you should consider creating a real table with values for the loop:

```
CREATE TABLE dummy_loop AS (
    SELECT
        n1.n + n10.n + n100.n AS n
    FROM
        (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) AS n1(n)
    CROSS JOIN
        (VALUES(0),(10),(20),(30),(40),(50),(60),(70),(80),(90)) AS n10(n)
    CROSS JOIN
        (VALUES(0),(100),(200),(300),(400),(500),(600),(700),(800),(900)) AS n100(n)
) WITH DATA;

ALTER TABLE dummy_loop ADD PRIMARY KEY (dummy_loop.n);
```

It depends on the reason for which you like to use it, but you could even create table for lets say for 100 years. It will be only 100*365 = 36500 rows with just a date field, so the table will be quite small and fast for joins.

```
CREATE TABLE dummy_dates AS (
    SELECT
        DATE('1970-01-01') + (n1.n + n10.n + n100.n) DAYS AS date
    FROM
        (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) AS n1(n)
    CROSS JOIN
        (VALUES(0),(10),(20),(30),(40),(50),(60),(70),(80),(90)) AS n10(n)
    CROSS JOIN
        (VALUES(0),(100),(200),(300),(400),(500),(600),(700),(800),(900)) AS n100(n)
) WITH DATA;

ALTER TABLE dummy_dates ADD PRIMARY KEY (dummy_dates.date);
```

And the select query could look like:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    dummy_days
WHERE
    date BETWEEN(:startDate, :endDate);
```

**EDIT 2**: Thanks to @Lennart suggestion I have changed TABLE(VALUES(..,..,..)) to VALES(..,..,..) because as he said TABLE is a synonym to LATERAL that was a real surprise for me.

**EDIT 3**: Thanks to @godric7gt I have removed TIMESTAMPDIFF and will remove from all my scripts, because as it is said in the documentation:

> These assumptions are used when converting the information in the second argument, which is a timestamp duration, to the interval type specified in the first argument. The **returned estimate may vary by a number of days**. For example, if the number of days (interval 16) is requested for the difference between '1997-03-01-00.00.00' and '1997-02-01-00.00.00', the result is 30. This is because the difference between the timestamps is 1 month, and the assumption of 30 days in a month applies.

It was a real surprise, because I was always trust this function for days difference.

Comment: Thank you for responding, yes I need an SQL only solution, I tried executing your query but I got the following error: " 16:47:41  [SELECT - 0 row(s), 0.580 secs]  1) [Error Code: -440, SQL State: 42884]  DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-440, SQLSTATE=42884, SQLERRMC=TIMESTAMPDIFF;FUNCTION, DRIVER=4.18.60. 2) [Error Code: -727, SQL State: 56098]  DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-727, SQLSTATE=56098, SQLERRMC=2;-440;42884;TIMESTAMPDIFF|FUNCTION, DRIVER=4.18.60
... 1 statement(s) executed, 0 row(s) affected, exec/fetch time: 0.580/0.000 sec  [0 successful, 0 warnings, 1 errors]
" Can you help debug?

Comment: Yes, of course, immediately after our network team got our VPN to the server working again :) I just need a working DB2 server to debug...

Comment: @godric7gt I have connected to the server, tested and fixed the query. You could try it by yourself, hope it will fix your issues. P.S. If you need to run it regularry consider having real table with dates as I show in last example.

Comment: @Mita, unless it is necessary for db2 for I, you can simplify your queries a bit. Table is a db2 synonym for lateral (works as well) and is not necessary in your query. Furthermore I believe that you can do: `select n from (values 1,2,3) t(n)` which is a bit more dense.

Comment: @Lennart Yes, the short syntax could be used, but I prefer the full. The short not does not give any benefits to the query, but could worse query readability. I prefer every time to use the full syntax with uppercase for the keywords and lowercase for the identifiers. It helps me read very easy even huge queries.

Comment: Using TABLE may cause additional burden on the optimizer since it opens up new possibilities that has to be taken into consideration. For a complex query this may degrade performance. You are probably aware of the purpose of TABLE (LATERAL), but I see it misused a lot due to unawareness of what it really means. That's why I made a comment on it.

Comment: @Lannart Thank you, I have checked the documentation and really TABLE is synonym of LATERAL :) Never know that...

Comment: Yes, they can both be be used in this context (I prefer LATERAL since it is standard). But when selecting from a table function you have to use the keyword TABLE. In a sense TABLE as in table function also allow us to reference variables otherwise hidden. I have not seen table functions mentioned in standard documents, so perhaps that's why  IBM exclusively use TABLE for functions and allow TABLE as an alias for LATERAL otherwise.

Comment: @Mita, thank you for the updated query, I tried using the date range '2015-02-01' and '2016-01-31', but its giving the output till 2016-01-27, please suggest. I did consider table, but considering in a lot of factors an sql only solution seems to be the only reasonable and troublefree solution.

Comment: @godric7gt I have just found that TIMESTAMPDIFF has an issue with date difference calculation! Thank you you have pointed me on that :) I will post a solution later, because I use it on production and rely that it will return me real days difference. I have an idea for a deterministic stored function that will return a real day difference.

Comment: @godric7gt The query is no more using TIMESTAMPDIFF and the returned period do not contain errors

Comment: @Mita, thank you, will check this out and revert back :)

Comment: @Mita, thank you, this is working perfectly :) Sorry for the delay in responding.

Answer (score 3):

For generating rows recusive SQL will needed.
Usually this looks like this in DB2:

```
with temp (date) as (
select date('23.02.2016') as date from sysibm.sysdummy1
union all
select date + 1 day from temp
where date < date('02.03.2016') 
)
```

select * from temp

For whatever reason a CTE (using WITH) should be avoided.
A possible workaround would be setting

```
db2set DB2_COMPATIBILITY_VECTOR=8
```

which enables the use of the Oracle style recusion with CONNECT BY

```
SELECT date('22.02.2016') + level days  as dt
  FROM sysibm.sysdummy1 CONNECT BY date('22.02.2016') + level days <= date('02.03.2016')
```

Please note: after setting the DB2_COMPATIBILITY_VECTOR a instance restart is necessary.

Comment: Thank you for replying :) I actually tried with connect by and level myself, but it doesnt seem to be working on my environment. My IDE is not giving me any proper error message either, so I am having a really hard time to debug.

Answer (score 0):

This solution doesn't use WITH, but it does use WHILE and a temp table...hopefully that meets your needs still?

EDIT -- I built this in SSMS 2014

```
DECLARE @Start DATE
DECLARE @End DATE

SET @Start = '2016-02-23'
SET @End = '2016-03-02'

CREATE TABLE #Dates ([Date] DATE)

WHILE @Start <= @End

BEGIN

INSERT INTO #Dates

SELECT @Start

SET @Start = DATEADD(Day,1,@Start)

END

SELECT * FROM #Dates

DROP TABLE #Dates
```

Comment: Sorry I need an SQL only solution, unfortunately due to some constraints on the environment I am on, I am unable to test this, thank you for your effort though :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume AS400 does not support recursive CTE's, and that's why you want a solution without them. I have no clue whether it supports any of the following constructions, but it might be worth a shot. First we will need a generator, any table with a sufficient number of rows will do. If you don't have a table large enough for the number of days you want you can create a cartesian product. Example:

```
select row_number() over ()
from a_table
cross join a_table
```

Another way of extending the domain is to create the powerset of a table using group by cube, see below.

Assume we one way or another can create a large enough set of rows. You can generate the dates like:

```
select date('23/02/2016') + n days
from (
    select row_number() over () as n
    from a_table
) as t
where n < 100
order by n
```

If for some reason you don't want to use an existing table, group by cube will produce a relation with a cardinality equal to the power set of the attributes. Here I use 4 columns which will generate 16 rows.

```
select date('2016-01-01') + row_number() over () days 
from sysibm.dual x 
group by cube(x.dummy, x.dummy, x.dummy, x.dummy)
```

If you want to generate say 100 rows you need 7 (since 2^7=128) attributes in the group by cube clause and a fetch first 100 rows:

```
select date('2016-01-01') + row_number() over () days 
from sysibm.dual x 
group by cube(x.dummy, x.dummy, x.dummy, x.dummy, x.dummy, x.dummy, x.dummy)
order by 1
fetch first 100 rows only
```

Comment: I tried executing the query as select '23/02/2016' + n days
from (
    select row_number() over () as n
    from sysibm.dual
) as t
where n < 100; but I am getting an error. Can you help debug this?

Comment: What error did you get? BTW, dual contains only one row som that won't do as a generator

Comment: You might have to cast the date to a date type, like `select date('2016-02-23') + ...`

Comment: did the casting and select date('20160223') + n days
from (
    select row_number() over () as n
    from reporter_status
) as t
where n < 100; is returning error " 17:46:59  [SELECT - 0 row(s), 0.577 secs]  [Error Code: -180, SQL State: 22007]  DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-180, SQLSTATE=22007, SQLERRMC=null, DRIVER=4.18.60
... 1 statement(s) executed, 0 row(s) affected, exec/fetch time: 0.577/0.000 sec  [0 successful, 0 warnings, 1 errors]
" does this help?

Comment: Try using some standard date representation like: '2016-02-13', the error means: SQL0180N  The syntax of the string representation of a datetime value is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks Lennart, its working now :) Made a few changes as per my requirement and the final query is like this select date('2016-01-31') -(n-1) days
from (
    select row_number() over () as n
    from reporter_status
) as t
where n<=days ('2016-01-31') - days (date('2015-02-01')-1 day)

Comment: DB2 (all recent versions) supports recursive CTEs.