# SQL Creating a list of date values based on starting date and ending dates

Tags: sql, db2

I have a data set with one observation:

```
id        Starting date        Ending date    
23         18/8/2013             26/4/2014
```

How would I be able to create a list of dates? i.e.

```
id       Date
23       Aug 2013
23       Sep 2013
23       Oct 2013
23       Nov 2013
23       Dec 2013
23       Jan 2014
23       Feb 2014
23       Mar 2014
23       Apr 2014
```

Comment: probably this can help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35578721/ibm-db2-generate-list-of-dates-between-two-dates

Comment: Juan Carlos Oropeza is right see my anser in the referenced link - a recursive query will help. You ask abut dates but you show months so you might need to use the month function ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IBM DB2: Generate list of dates between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35578721/ibm-db2-generate-list-of-dates-between-two-dates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a SQL Table-Valued Function as below, this will generate the dates.

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_GenerateDates
(
    @StartDate DATETIME, 
    @EndDate DATETIME
)

RETURNS @Output TABLE 
(
      Value NVARCHAR(4000)
)

AS

BEGIN

    INSERT INTO @Output
    SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(MONTH, @StartDate, @EndDate)+1) --get only the dates where dates are between the source startdate and enddate
            DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, number, @StartDate)) + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH, number, @StartDate))) AS Months
        FROM [master].dbo.spt_values 
        WHERE [type] = N'P' 
        ORDER BY number

    RETURN
END
```

Then your SELECT statement

```
SELECT tn.id,
    dates.Value 
FROM TableName tn
CROSS APPLY dbo.fn_GenerateDates(tn.StartDate, tn.EndDate) AS dates
ORDER BY tn.id
```

Answer (score 0):

This [link](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0401kuznetsov/index.html) uses DB2 as reference, but same concept can be used for SQL Server with little modifications.

This Approach is Similar to the answer provided by @mvisser

Using Sys.columns to generate the dates

Create A SQL Function to Generate the Dates

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_GenerateDates
(
    @StartDate DATETIME, 
    @EndDate DATETIME
)

RETURNS @Outputdates TABLE 
(
      Dates NVARCHAR(4000)
)

AS

BEGIN

INSERT INTO @Outputdates
-- Uses Sys.columns Table to Add Months to Given Startdate -----
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH,gen_date) + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),YEAR(gen_date)) FROM 
        (SELECT DATEADD(month,(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY name) - 1),@StartDate) gen_date FROM SYS.COLUMNS) a
    WHERE gen_date between @StartDate and @EndDate
RETURN
END
```

Then use Select statement

```
SELECT t.id,gen_dates.Dates
FROM TableName t
CROSS APPLY dbo.fn_GenerateDates(t.StartDate, t.EndDate) AS gen_dates
ORDER BY t.id
```